# android studio - automatically remove unused resource

Tags: android-studio

Android lint tools seems only can **detect** unused resources but **remove** those resources.
Is there any way to remove those unused resource automatically?

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2016-05: here's the final solution:**

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking

--- old answer ---
No as far as I know.

Are you using linux/Mac? I developed a script by myself to do this:

Layout files, execute in the layout directory:

```
for f in *; do f=`echo $f | sed 's/.xml//g'`; echo $f; grep layout.$f -r ../../src .. >/dev/null; if [ $? != 0 ]; then rm $f.xml;fi done
```

Pictures: execute in project root directory

```
find . -name "*png" -o -name "*jpg" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'|awk -F. '{print $1}'|sort|uniq > imgs
for f in `cat imgs`; do echo $f; grep drawable.$f -r src res >/dev/null; if [ $? != 0 ]; then find res -name $f.* -exec rm {} \; ;fi; done
```

Comment: No it doesn't. you may want to try cygwin but again, would be easy to make all these working.

Comment: @Shawn, Can you pls explain a little bit more about how your script work ?

Comment: I just keep getting no such file or directory, I must probably be doing something wrong or need to edit your script, would be usefull if you explain the script a bit.

Comment: If someone is working with this, note that the src and res path's are probably different from the script, that's why it's not working properly out of the box. Also, do check if the right files are being added with the first line :). When I ran it it was just adding all files to the imgs file